# Requiring only one of two dependencies in a requirements file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, requirements.txt

Some Python packages require one of two packages as a dependency. For example, `Ghost.py` requires either `PySide` or `PyQt4`.

Is it possible to include such a dependency in a `requirements.txt` file? Is there any 'or' operator that works with these files?

If not, what can I do to add these requirements to the file so only one of them will be installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently neither pip's `requirement.txt` nor setuptools directly allow such a construction. Both require you to specify a list of requirements. You can restrict the version of a requirement, but that's all.

Inside Python, you can handle this situation as follows:

```
try:
    import dependency1

    def do_it(x):
        return dependency1.some_function(x)
except ImportError:
    try:
        import dependency2

        def do_it(x)
            return dependency2.another_function(x)
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError('You must install either dependency1 or '
                          + 'dependecy2!')
```

Now `do_it` uses either `dependency1.some_function` or `dependency2.another_function`, depending on which is available.

That will still leave you with the problem of how to specify your requirements. I see two options:

1. Don't formally specify the requirement in `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` but document that the user needs to install one of the dependencies. This approach might be OK if the setup of your software requires additional manual steps anyway (i.e. more than just `pip install my_tool`).
2. Hard-code your preferred requirement in `requirements.txt` or `setup.py`.

In the end, you have to ask yourself why people might want to use one dependency over the other: I usually couldn't care less about the dependencies of the libraries that I use, because (disk) space is cheap and (due to virtualenv) there is little risk of incompatibilities. I'd therefore even suggest you think about not supporting two different dependencies for the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a small Python script to accomplish this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
packages = 'p1 p2 p3'.split()

try:
    import optional1
except ImportError: # opt1 not installed 
    try:
        import optional2
    except ImportError: # opt2 not installed
        packages.append('optional2')

print(' '.join(packages))
```

Have this script executable with

```
chmod +x requirements.py
```

And finally run pip with it like this:

```
pip install $(requirements.py)
```

The '$(requirements.py)' will execute the requirements.py script and put its output (in this case, a list of packages) into pip install ...

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you can use such syntax with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

For setuptools, you can change the `setup` code to look similar to here:
https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/setup.py#L11

Where `dependency1` would be installed if none of `dependency1` and `dependency2` is installed yet, but nothing is installed if any of them is already part of the system.

The caveat is that it doesn't work with wheels, and you need to install with `--no-binary` to make it work: https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/installation/#note-on-opencv-dependencies